# App Settings doesn't remove in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing apps using Xamarin.Forms, the app stored some data as App Settings, the issue is when I removed the app from the Android phone and installed it again, the old AppSettings doesn't remove.

Comment: How exactly are you configuring your app settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because *Auto Backup for Apps* automatically backs up a user's data from apps that target and run on Android 6.0 (API level 23) or later. This happens when [allowBackup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#allowBackup) is set to `true`.

You have to change it in your android manifest (Go to your Android project -> Properties -> open the manifest -> go to Source view below) by adding it to your application tag and set it to `false`:

```
<application android:allowBackup="false" android:fullBackupContent="false" ...>
...
</application>
```

Also set [fullBackupContent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fullBackupContent) to `false` to be sure none of the data is backed up.

You can have more info in [Back up user data with Auto Backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup)

HIH